# Can't push cell data in UITableViewCell to new UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue, nsobject, indexpath

I'm new to coding, but I've been working on the same issue for days. I'm trying to push the `menuItem` to join an array in a new view controller scene called `OrderController` when the cell row is selected. `menuItem` is a class, and it gets added to an array of `MenuItems` in `OrderList` on the next page.

The closest I was to making this happen was putting `orderList.add` within the `didSelectRowAt` function, but it would just take the `orderList` from the current `TableView`, but this method doesn't work well because it won't update the values on the next page.

This is the code below:

```
var orderList = OrderList()
let menuItems = PaneraMenu()
var menuItem = MenuItems()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let row = indexPath.row
    let order = menuItems.items[row]
    navigationItem.title! = order.name
    orderList.add(menuItem: order)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "paneSell"{
        let yo = segue.destination as! OrderController

        yo.orderList = orderList
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two links to help you better understand pass data between `ViewController`s.
[This is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guSYMPaXLaw)
[This is a webpage](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Using-UITableView)

I suggest use `protocol` instead of `prepare for segue`.